# restangular query does not working?

Tags: angularjs, restangular, satellizer

I am running this code. 
people collection contains 20 peoples and every body has friends list field containing 6 friends. 
query written in below not return in any data. but if you remove query then it return 20 people.
My doubt is bellow code correct or wrong.

```
 Restangular.one('people',JSON.parse(user_id)).get().then(function(user) {
            $scope.user = user;
            $scope.infinitePosts = new InfinitePosts(user);
            if (user.friends.length !== 0) {
                console.log($scope.user.friends)
                Restangular.all('people').getList({
                    where: {
                        "_id": {
                            "$in": $scope.user.friends
                        }
                    }
                }).then(function(friend) {
                    console.log("------------------")
                    console.log(friend)
                    $scope.friends = friend;
                });
```

total code here below.

```
angular.module('weberApp')
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $auth, Restangular, InfinitePosts, $alert,     $http, CurrentUser, UserService) {
    $scope.UserService = UserService;

    $http.get('/api/me', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': $auth.getToken()
        }
    }).success(function(user_id) {
        Restangular.one('people',JSON.parse(user_id)).get().then(function(user) {
            $scope.user = user;
            $scope.infinitePosts = new InfinitePosts(user);
            if (user.friends.length !== 0) {
                console.log($scope.user.friends)
                Restangular.all('people').getList({
                    where: {
                        "_id": {
                            "$in": $scope.user.friends
                        }
                    }
                }).then(function(friend) {
                    console.log("------------------")
                    console.log(friend)
                    $scope.friends = friend;
                });
            }
            $scope.submit_post = function() {
                $scope.infinitePosts.addPost($scope.new_post);
                $scope.new_post = '';
            };
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Any errors in the console? How does the request look like? Have you tried trouble shooting the server response?